# QT C++ error: undefined reference to `vtable for appprinter'

Tags: c++, qt

question:
i have a program that includes a printer class 'apppprinter',
but when trying to compile i get the error:

```
appprinter.cpp:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `vtable for appprinter'
appprinter.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `vtable for appprinter'
appprinter.o: In function `appprinter::printIt()':
make: Leaving directory `/home/michael/projectOOI/HerkansingProjectOOI-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release'
appprinter.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `appprinter::staticMetaObject'
appprinter.cpp:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `appprinter::staticMetaObject'
appprinter.cpp:(.text+0x23d): undefined reference to `appprinter::staticMetaObject'
appprinter.cpp:(.text+0x3ab): undefined reference to `appprinter::staticMetaObject'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

header file:

```
#ifndef APPPRINTER_H
#define APPPRINTER_H
#include<QObject>
#include<QWidget>
#include <QMap>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QCalendarWidget>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QString>
#include <QtGui>
#include "appointment.h"

class appprinter : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    appprinter(QWidget * parent = 0, int i = 0, int option = 0);
    ~appprinter(){}
    void setList(QList<appointment> param) {goTo = param; printIt();}
    void printIt();
public slots:
    void goNext() {showIter++; this->close();appprinter * help = new appprinter(this,showIter);help->setList(goTo); help->show();}
    void goPrev() {showIter--; this->close();appprinter * help = new appprinter(this,showIter);help->setList(goTo); help->show();}
private:
    int showIter;
    QList<appointment> goTo;
    bool isUnder;
    int opt;
};

#endif // appprinter_H
```

cpp file:

```
#include "appprinter.h"

appprinter::appprinter(QWidget * parent, int i, int option)
        : QWidget(parent)
{
    showIter = i;
    if (option == 0);//needs further building

}

void appprinter::printIt()
{
    QList<appointment> list = goTo;
    int i = showIter;
    QPushButton * showNext = new QPushButton(tr("Next"));
    connect(showNext,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(goNext()));
    QPushButton * showPrev = new QPushButton(tr("Previous"));
    connect(showPrev,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(goPrev()));
    QPushButton * closer = new QPushButton(tr("Close"));
    connect(closer,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));

    QGridLayout * lay = new QGridLayout;
    int counter = 0;
    QLabel * pTitle = new QLabel;
    QTextEdit * pDescription = new QTextEdit;
    QLabel * pDeadline = new QLabel;
    QLabel * pDeadlineTime = new QLabel;
    QLabel * pPriority = new QLabel;
    QLabel * pStatus = new QLabel;
    QLabel * emptyList = new QLabel(tr("No search results!"));

    if (list.count() != 0)
    {
        pTitle->setText(list[i].ShowTitle());
        pDescription->setText(list[i].ShowDescription());
        pDeadline->setText(list[i].ShowDate().toString());
        pDeadlineTime->setText(list[i].ShowStart().toString());
        if (i+1 >= list.count())
            showNext->hide();
        else
            showNext->show();
        if (i <= 0)
            showPrev->hide();
        else
            showPrev->show();
        lay->addWidget(pTitle,counter++,0);
        lay->addWidget(pDescription,counter++,0);
        lay->addWidget(pDeadline,counter++,0);
        lay->addWidget(pDeadlineTime,counter++,0);
        lay->addWidget(pPriority,counter++,0);
        lay->addWidget(pStatus,counter++,0);
        lay->addWidget(showPrev,counter,0,Qt::AlignLeft);
        lay->addWidget(showNext,counter,0,Qt::AlignRight);
        lay->addWidget(closer,++counter,0,Qt::AlignCenter);
        this->setFixedHeight(320);
    }
    else
    {
        lay->addWidget(emptyList,0,0);
        lay->addWidget(closer,1,0,Qt::AlignCenter);
        this->setFixedHeight(240);
    }
    setLayout(lay);

    if (list.count() != 0)
        setWindowTitle(list[i].ShowTitle());
}
```

does anyone know a solution??

Comment: Have you provided definition for all the virtual functions of `QWidget` in your `appprinter` class? Only pure virtual functions can exist without a definition, All virtual functions **must** have an definition.

Comment: If I remember correctly there is no pure virtuals in QWidget

Comment: this is actually a copied class, exact copy of another one in the build, yet this doesnt compile and the other does, the only thing that has changed is the name printer to appprinter

Comment: clean all. run qmake again. and rebuild all

Comment: just run `qmake` && `make` again to `moc` your class

Comment: Make the destructor virtual...

Comment: @Papergay: if base class destructor is virtual you don't have to do it.

Comment: Hmm. And what if this class becomes a parent for an other class?

Comment: Papergay: If the parent class dtor is virtual, the subclass dtor is implicitly virtual, too. So it doesn't matter if you put "virtual" in front or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you face this type of situation always do a `clean`, `qmake` and rebuild. It fixes unless you have other problems like missing `Q_OBJECT` or unimplemented pure virtuals.