# Qt/C++ : Centralise parameters in one class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to centralise some parameters in one class. I looked on several forums and tutorials without finding any real answer. Maybe I don't use Qt correctly.

I have a Qt class *Application* which handles theses parameters.

**Application.h**

```
class Application : public QApplication
{
     public:
        Application(int, char**);
        ~Application();
        bool setFilesPath(QString path);
        QString getFilesPath();

    private:
        QString filesPath;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;

    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I'd like to access the `setFilesPath()` and `getFilesPath()` methods from everywhere (for exemple in another class. Therefore a made Application inherit from QApplication, hoping that `qApp.setFilesPath()` would work. But it doesnt.

It seems to be a quite usual thing to access some parameters from everywhere. So how could one do this ?

I've found this three ways :

- Global variables
- Static methods
- Including an instance of Application in every class needing the method (but it seems wrong)

Which is more commonly used (and why) ? Why does my way doesn't work ?

Thank you.

*EDIT:*
In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920527/qt-c-accessing-mainwindow-ui-from-a-different-class?rq=1), they use singelton design pattern.
So calling

```
Application *app = Application::getInstance();
```

everywhere I need it. Is it better ?

Comment: Look at the QSettings class.

Comment: I know that. I've found it of course. But it's quite limited. And I may not want to remember this for the next session. I just want to use some parameters in every class. Not to remember it.

Comment: The singleton seems the way to go, if you need to access the `Application` instance from everywhere. You can use the build-in sinqleton from QApplication, and downcast it. However, keep in mind a singleton is (almost) a global variable, and thus should be avoided the rest of the time. A question: what is `qApp`, from `qApp.setFilesPath()`?

Comment: qApp was the pointer on the QApplication object (see answer below : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23777420/3284719))

Comment: Why combine it with the application class?

Comment: What would you propose instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your class using `qApp` pointer. According to the Qt documentation:

> A global pointer referring to the unique application object. It is
>   equivalent to the pointer returned by the QCoreApplication::instance()
>   function except that, in GUI applications, it is a pointer to a
>   QApplication instance.

So, your code somewhere could look like:

```
Application *myApp = qobject_cast<Application *>(qApp);
QString path = myApp->getFilesPath();
```

Comment: Is casting something "pretty" and safe ?

Comment: I did it and your first line makes an error : erreur : invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'QStaticAssertFailure<false>'
     enum {Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN(q_static_assert_result, __COUNTER__) = sizeof(QStaticAssertFailure<!!(Condition)>)}

Comment: @ochurlaud, in this case yes. You can also check myApp against being null, if you want. The error message is because you did not use `Q_OBJECT` macro in your `Application` class - this is required to make signals/slots work.

Comment: You need Q_OBJECT for qobject_cast.

Comment: @ochurlaud: Btw, if you had used 5.2.0 or later with C++11 support, you would have received a static assert about the missing macro.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Thx you, you were right, i forgot the Q_OBJECT. For people having problems then, don't forget to clean, qmake, rebuild as said in [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12035963/3284719)

Comment: If someone could upvote my topic : I need 5 points of rep to upvote this answer :P

Answer (score 0):

You can have your classes in the main independently and connect a signal from each class that needs to access the value in your class to the slot that returns the value :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;

    MyClass myclass1;

    QObject::connect(&mainWindow,SIGNAL(askFilesPath()),myclass1,SLOT(getFilesPath()));

    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This way when you call the signal askFilesPath() in your MainWindow, the slot in your custom class gets called and the value is returned:

```
QString filePath = askFilesPath();
```

You should note that if the two classes are in different threads then the connection type should be `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`.

Comment: I think you miss `QObject::` from the connect.

Comment: I knew this solution but it's means connecting every class to Application. I prefer the other anwser. Thx for your idea, though